# Axon Event Sourcing not generating table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, axon

I am learning how to use the axon framework for event sourcing, seems to be going good but I have gotten stuck on the database configuration for event sourcing. From what I understood from docs / other articles, the database table should automatically generate.

I first tried with H2, the database table was generated by itself, everything working fine.
I added my own mysql db, and the database table is not being created.. I'm getting the error

```
'Table 'producttest.domain_event_entry' doesn't exist
```

I was under the impression that the table will generate itself, I must be doing something wrong here, but I'm unsure what. Could anyone help me please?

My code:

ProductAggregate class

```
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;

import java.util.UUID;

import static org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateLifecycle.apply;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Aggregate
@Slf4j
public class ProductAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String productId;

    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;

    @CommandHandler
    public ProductAggregate(ProductCreateCommand command){
        log.info("handling {}", command);
        apply(new ProductCreatedEvent(command.getProductId(),command.getProductName(),command.getProductDescription()));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void onProductCreateEvent(ProductCreatedEvent event){
        log.info("applying {}", event);
        this.productId = event.getProductId();
        this.productName = event.getProductName();
        this.productDescription = event.getProductDescription();
    }
}
```

ProductCreateCommand

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.TargetAggregateIdentifier;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductCreateCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;

}
```

ProductCreatedEvent

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.TargetAggregateIdentifier;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductCreatedEvent {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;

}
```

TestRunner

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGateway;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.UUID;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;

    @Autowired
    public TestRunner(CommandGateway commandGateway) {
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        log.info("sending product create command");
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new ProductCreateCommand(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Oreo", "biscuit"));
        log.info("sending product create command");
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(new ProductCreateCommand(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Oreo", "biscuit"));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

application.properties file

```
logging.level.root=info
server.port=8090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/producttest
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= false
```

logs:

```
2021-01-06 21:44:51.229  INFO 21236 --- [           main] c.u.e.a.Client.TestRunner                : sending product create command
2021-01-06 21:44:51.257  INFO 21236 --- [           main] c.u.e.a.Aggregate.ProductAggregate       : handling ProductCreateCommand(productId=638643b7-1e4f-45b5-bfa9-1c2fd9360fa3, productName=Oreo, productDescription=biscuit)
2021-01-06 21:44:51.260  INFO 21236 --- [           main] c.u.e.a.Aggregate.ProductAggregate       : applying ProductCreatedEvent(productId=638643b7-1e4f-45b5-bfa9-1c2fd9360fa3, productName=Oreo, productDescription=biscuit)
2021-01-06 21:44:51.321  WARN 21236 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2021-01-06 21:44:51.321 ERROR 21236 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'producttest.domain_event_entry' doesn't exist
2021-01-06 21:44:51.333  INFO 21236 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-06 21:44:51.346 ERROR 21236 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Comment: I would be more interested in your `application.properties` (or `yml`). In short, you have to instruct JPA to create it for you or provide scripts (flyway, liquibase, etc) to do it for you. I would recommend the latter approach.

Comment: Hi @LucasCampos I have added the application.properties file to the post. I think I will try to get this to work, and then as you said for when I try to actually implement this into my real application, I guess I can look into what flyway/liquibase are.

Comment: seems like I was missing `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` , I should go read up more on JPA :). Thanks for the hint though, appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! I've added it as an answer than you can accept and everyone is aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should instruct your application how to create tables.

You have 2 options:

1. Tell JPA to do that, adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` or `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`
2. Use a more robust tool like `flyway`, `liquibase`, etc

All the other configs you showed looks fine.